# Why did my Faucet's Metal Braided Hose Fail / Explode?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, hose

Two years ago we installed an expensive high end branded (Lifetime warranty) single holed faucet in our laundry room.

Last week the metal braided hose on the cold side burst. The way our faucet is designed is that the hose is attached to the faucet itself, so it was not a 3rd party or cheaply made metal braided hose. Luckily we quickly noticed the leak, and the damage was not that severe, but it could have been much worse! But the  idea that these hoses can fail only after 2 year is very very very troubling to say the least.

After doing little bit more research. According to this  [MIT paper](https://dspace.mit.edu/openaccess-disseminate/1721.1/103065) written in March 2016, it discusses the failures of metal braided hoses.

Few points in the conclusion is the quality of the steel. **But as I've said before, ours is attached to the high end faucet, so i'm assuming it's of the highest quality.**

Storing cleaning agents under the sink which can contain chlorides or other corrosive compounds. **But we don't store anything in this particular cabinet. So that's ruled out.**

I've read on other sources: suggesting to make sure not to over tighten or under tighten the hose. **Okay???**

That you should replace the metal braided hose every 5 years. **That's not possible in my situation because they are attached to the faucet.**

And that you should have a licensed plumber install the faucets. Why? What is a Licensed Plumber going to do differently than a person with a wrench and a common understanding of how to install things. This shouldn't exactly be rocket science.

The faucet company has already sent me a brand new replacement of the unit, but now i'm skeptical in installing it again. If we didn't catch this leak, it could have costed us thousands of dollars in repairs.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Here are a few images.

[image]
[image]

This is not my faucet, but an exmaple of how the hose looks. I've faded out the 3rd hose because my faucet only has two hoses, not three. 
[image]

Edit: 
isherwood suggested the discoloration could be rust. It's possible, but I think it may be rust dust? Here are couple pictures of the surrounding area. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see the bottom of the sink is rusted out, and if you wipe it, "rust dust" comes off and could fall down toward the hoses. I'm not super knowledgeable about rust dust, or rust itself.

Any thoughts?

High Resolution Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZIp6.jpg

Comment: All things have a rate of failure > 0. Maybe it was a manufacturing defect or maybe whoever installed it damaged it during the installation or ??? I think the why is not a question that can be guaranteed to be accurate in this case. I do think you have the makings of a great question on how to install/replace the line yourself. I recommend altering the question toward that end. Make/model and pic of the faucet would be helpful.

Comment: That's pretty nuts the way the metal strands are torn. I wonder if there was a pressure anomaly, such as [water hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_hammer), that resulted in momentary extreme pressure. I wouldn't expect to see failure of that nature at typical residential pressure. It's reasonable to expect a service life of 20 years or more with that type of hose.

Comment: @unhandledexcepsean I've updated the question to show an example of how the hoses come out of our faucet.

Comment: There does seem to be some discoloration of the metal near the failure. Can you explain that?

Comment: @isherwood It could be saw dust or rust dust? I'm really not sure. I can take more pictures of the surrounding area near where the faucet was installed if you want.

Comment: If it's rust, the braid isn't "high quality" as it isn't stainless steel, and it would explain the breach. It would also seem to indicate a persistent leak issue.

Comment: @isherwood I've updated the question for you.

Comment: The degree of rust in those latest photos raises my eyebrows. You either have a lot of moisture present, or you've had an incident of chemical damage. Some acids will almost instantly rust metal like that.

Comment: The parts diagram and list for the faucet may show that those hoses can be replaced.

Comment: @jimstewart According to the RMA department, the hose can't be replaced. The whole faucet had to be replaced. Which is why they sent me a brand new faucet i guess.

Comment: What is the brand name of the faucet? Your statement that it is "expensive high end" and that "it was not a... cheaply made... hose" may not necessarily be true; and price is not always an indicator of quality. The fact that rubber hoses (yes, they have a braided metal jacket, they are still rubber or vinyl) were deliberately designed to be not replaceable makes me suspicious of the quality.

Comment: American Standard. Faucet runs about $250 for a single hole.

Comment: When the standard clothes washer hoses were the black reinforced rubber ones there was a lot of flooding when these ruptured after long service. I haven't heard of that occurring with the new braided ss covered ones which I have hoped were *silicone* rubber inside (and so might last indefinitely). Is there any authoritative information on the material of these hoses? There is one type of ss covered washer hose (Floodsafe is one brand) which has automatic cutoff valves in the washer ends which close under wide open flow. The need for this feature must mean that these hoses might rupture.

Answer (score 3):

You specify that the location is a laundry room.

I wonder if there are hammer arrestors (newfangled) or dead air spaces (oldfangled, may need draining the pipes once in a while to maintain) on the waterlines serving the washing machine, a prime culprit of high flow rates combined with quick-acting solenoid valves for the finest production of water hammer any household appliance can manage (equalled but not exceeded by the dishwasher, in some cases.)

Water hammer (whether or not it rattles the pipes so you hear it) is a sudden spike in water pressure caused by the inertia of flowing water in the pipe, when the place it's flowing to is quickly shut off. As a somewhat flexible item in close proximity to the end-point of the washer lines, the faucet hoses might be getting stressed by the repetitive pressure pulses.

A water hammer arrestor is basically a very small pressure tank, located at the end of the line to provide a compressible (gas/air) buffer. Water is effectively incompressible, and as such the pressure reached in the absence of an air chanber or arrestor can be quite high.

While it may be comforting to think that the high end faucet maker means only the highest-quality components, it may not be true. In this case, you may simply be exceeding the rated pressure on a brief, but regular basis - until failure results. If, perchance, the hose was kinked or in any way damaged (possibly in shipping and handling rather than though anything you did to it) that would make a weak spot in the hose.

Comment: It is possible to put a twist in these flexible hoses in installation; this could cause failure. I know these flexible hoses are now the standard for faucets and toilets, but with progessively  more installations and each one treated as having an indefinite service life, it may turn out that they have a failure rate higher than hoped for and expected.

Comment: I mean, this makes sense. It is something to consider. But for water hammering to break my faucet hose... It seems a bit far fetched to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me a couple of days ago. The water got turned off because of maintenance work in the building and they turned it back on after a couple hours. Everything was great, but around 2am the hose burst and flooded my apartment, it was running for 2 hours straight, max pressure. I have no idea why that happened...the hose is under my sink and the kitchen is made of wood. I still have sequels of the incident...[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/166232)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).